# Expectation operator and logarithmic function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, logarithm

$$\frac{1}{C_t}=E_t\left[\beta \frac{1}{C_{t+1}} \right]R_{t+1}$$

How to log linearise the function? $C_{t+1}$ is the stochastic term; $\beta$ is known.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Expectations don't carry through nonlinear transformation. I agree with Aksakal - what are you trying to do?

Comment: In economics, we have something called Euler Equation. In the paper I'm reading, the author managed to get it into this form: 
c(t)=-r(t+1)+E(t){c(t+1)}, where all the letters are now small letters. c(t) is deviation from steady state. I'm not sure how he got into this form.

Comment: Please provide the reference of the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be modest: the Euler equation is not "something we have in economics": it is a piece of mathematics that we use in economics. To add some context, the equation stated in the question is the optimal rule for the intertemporal evolution of consumption $C_t$, in a stochastic context. $\beta$ is the gross discount factor (with which future values are discounted by economic agents to obtain their present value), and empirically it takes values less but close to zero, $\beta \in [0.96,0.99]$. It is assumed constant. $R_{t+1}$ is the gross return on wealth, $R_{t+1} = 1+r_{t+1}$ where $r_{t+1}$ is the interest rate, and is  considered exogenously given and non-random.

The approximation steps needed to arrive at the expression the OP gives in the comments are as follows:

**A)** Take natural logarithms:

$$-\ln C_t = \ln \beta + \ln R_{t+1} + \ln\Big(E_t[1/C_{t+1}]\Big) \qquad [1]$$

**B)** Argue that since $\beta \approx 1 \Rightarrow \ln \beta \approx 0$

**C)** Argue that since the interest rate is usually "small" (less than $0.1$), then $\ln R_{t+1} = \ln (1+r_{t+1}) \approx r_{t+1}$

Insert these into $[1]$ to obtain

$$-\ln C_t = r_{t+1} + \ln\Big(E_t[1/C_{t+1}]\Big) \qquad [2]$$

Denote $C^*$ the steady-state value of consumption (a constant), and consider the 1st-order Taylor expansion of $\ln\Big(E_t[1/C_{t+1}]\Big)$ around $C^*$:

$$\ln\Big(E_t[1/C_{t+1}]\Big) \approx ln\Big(E_t[1/C^*]\Big) + \frac {1}{E_t[1/C_{t+1}]}\cdot \frac {\partial {E_t[1/C_{t+1}]}}{\partial C_{t+1}}\Big |_{C^*}  \cdot (C_{t+1} - C^*)$$

Under the conditions that permit to take the derivative operator inside the expected value, and given that $C^*$ is a constant we have

$$\ln\Big(E_t[1/C_{t+1}]\Big) \approx -lnC^* - C^*\cdot \frac {1}{(C^*)^2} \cdot (C_{t+1} - C^*) = -lnC^* - \frac {1}{C^*} \cdot (C_{t+1} - C^*)$$

Insert this into $[2]$ to get

$$-\ln C_t = r_{t+1}  -lnC^* - \frac {1}{C^*} \cdot (C_{t+1} - C^*) \\
\Rightarrow \ln (C_t/C^*) = - r_{t+1} + \frac {C_{t+1} - C^*}{C^*} \qquad [3]$$

Now use the approximation $\ln (C_t/C^*) \approx \frac {C_{t} - C^*}{C^*}$ and take expectations as of time $t$ to arrive at

$$\frac {C_{t} - C^*}{C^*} = - r_{t+1} + \frac {E_tC_{t+1} - C^*}{C^*}  \qquad [4]$$

In other words we are talking about *percentage* deviations from the steady-state. Defining then $c_t \equiv \frac {C_{t} - C^*}{C^*}$ and analogously for $t+1$ we arrive at the equation given by the OP in the comments,

$$c_t = - r_{t+1} + E_tc_{t+1}  \qquad [5]$$

Comment: (+1) for "Let's be modest: the Euler equation is not "something we have in economics": it is a piece of mathematics that we use in economics."